# I need to know how to execute python shell comand and get constant output

Tags: javascript, python, magic-mirror

(sorry for my bad english), Im making a Magic Mirror and Im developing a Module for that. I had done a script in python and I need to print consantly the shell of the script because is a "While True". For that I need to do a child process but my problem is: while my script is running it doest print anything in the log console or the mirror.

The file of node_helper.js --->

```
var NodeHelper = require("node_helper")
var { spawn } = require("child_process")

var self = this

async function aexec() {
        const task = spawn('python3', ['/Fotos/reconeixementfacial.py'])
        task.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
                console.log(`${data}`)
        })
        task.stdout.on('exit', (data) => {
                console.log("exit")
        })
        task.stdout.on('error', (data) => {
                console.log(`${error}`)
        })
        task.unref()
}

module.exports = NodeHelper.create({
        start: function() {
                aexec()
        },
        socketNotificationReceived: function(notification, payload) {
                console.log(notification)
        }
})
```

Thank you so much for the time !!
Note: If my python script doesnt have a "while true" (only a sequence), it works, only doesnt work if my script is undifined

Answer (score 0):

Ofc I don't know how you use the exported module but I assume you just run the start function to block your process but as Docs say `spawn` is async and doesn't block the loop and you added the async function which made it a promise.

So if you want it to be async you have to properly handle promises in the current module and all others which call it:

```
var NodeHelper = require("node_helper")
var { spawn } = require("child_process")

var self = this

function aexec() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let result = '';
        const task = spawn('python3', ['/Fotos/reconeixementfacial.py'])
        task.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
                console.log(`${data}`)
                result += data.toString() // accumulate
        })
        task.stdout.on('exit', (data) => {
                console.log("exit")
                task.unref()
                resolve(result) // return from promise (async)
        })
        task.stdout.on('error', (data) => {
                console.log(`${error}`)
                task.unref()
                reject()
        })
    });
}

module.exports = NodeHelper.create({
        start: function() {
                aexec().then((result) => console.log(result))
        },
        socketNotificationReceived: function(notification, payload) {
                console.log(notification)
        }
})
```

Or simple use blocking version of spawning a child process: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options
Which should be much simpler

Comment: What I require is to get the output of the program at the same time it's being executed. The issue by using this, is that I only get the output once the program ends.

Comment: The easiest way to use `spawnSync` without any processes
`let result = require('child_process').spawnSync('ls').stdout.toString()` 
Instead of `ls` your command. The result of stdout is bytestream and has to be decoded to string

Comment: I'm not interested on using this exec as Sync, the idea is that it's a background async process on my parent process, and it's constantly running on a while(true) until the entire program ends. What I want is to get this output without closing the shell command or waiting it to end.

Comment: Then use promise as I showed in the answer, the only difference is if you want result to be returned from the function pass it to `resolve` function, I will update the answer

Comment: Here we end up on the same result. What I need is to get the log while the Python code is being executed: The same moment the print() method is done, I require this message. It's like a server class, I can't wait until it ends, also I can't end the process cause that's not the purpose of this code, cause this I need any kind of solution that allows me to get the output on an async way and without having to close the process for this.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. But since it's already a stream you can just use it then. Could you provide usecase how you are going to use the output and I'd maybe help you how to change the script.